# How to get Image Name in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 Buttons in My activity. 1st One: Upload Image 2nd One: Get Uploaded image name. Now i have Pressed "Upload Image" Button and selected a image from gallery and that image is displayed in ImageView. Then i Pressed 2nd Button "Get Uploaded Image Name" and a Toast will display the name of that image which is in ImageView. I want the code of this only.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Uri uri = data.getData();
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAlbumsList.clear();
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Album album = new Album();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID);
            album.id = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            if (!ids.contains(album.id)) {
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
                album.name = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                album.coverID = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

                mAlbumsList.add(album);
                ids.add(album.id);
            } else {
                mAlbumsList.get(ids.indexOf(album.id)).count++;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for replying. By using above code do i get all images names which are there in gallery??

Comment: Sir i just want name of that image which i uploaded to ImageView.

Comment: check my edited answers it gives you only selected image name

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that you can retrieve the image name.. :

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String selectedImageName = selectedImage.getLastPathSegment();
```